# Loading of material design lite

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, material-design-lite

I wanted to use the material design lite library on my asp.net webform page, but I have load problems with some components.
For example with the radio button element. When the page loads, it shows the styled radio button first and after 1 second it loads the material style. This looks very ugly. I tried to include the resources on different positions but nothing helps. With my other ui frameworks I don't have these problems and when I run a plain html example it works perfectly.

Comment: Yea this is a programming question. i'm asking what could cause the mdl libary load so late? I only have this problem with asp. Plain html works fine. I tried to remove all other javascript and css includes and include the mdl on different positions.

Comment: Since this is obviously someone new to the site and programming, you should probably read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help get better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. You have to upgrade the elements earlier

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
});
```